# FreeNX NoMachine

Tags: nomachine, freenx

Is there a way to toggle between full screen and a window viewing with FreeNX nomachine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [ArchWiki FreeNX](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FreeNX) page:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> toggles full-screen mode
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> maximizes or minimizes the window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> is the emergency exit and kill-window shortcut, in case the remote session is not responding

[This source](http://www.opensourcetutor.com/2007/07/21/nomachine-freenx-fullscreen-switching/) also mentions the "Magic Pixel".  When in full-screen mode, you can get back to your local desktop by clicking the "Magic Pixel" on the top-right corner of the screen.  Just move the mouse cursor to the top right and left-click.